# How to do a bubble sort in python using socket on a TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

This is my server side - which need to be TCP, so I need accept and listen, I can't use UDP.

```
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread


class ThreadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, sock2):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._socket = sock2
        self._run = True

    def bubble(self, x):
        length = len(x)
        for i in range(0, length):
            swapped = False
            for element in range(0, length - i - 1):
                if x[element] > x[element + 1]:
                    hold = x[element + 1]
                    x[element + 1] = x[element]
                    x[element] = hold
                    swapped = True
            if not swapped:
                break

    def run(self):
        while self._run:
            data_num = self._socket.recv(1024)
            number = data_num.split(" ")
            sort_num = []

            for num in number:
                sort_num.append(num)

            self.bubble(sort_num)

            for num in sort_num:
                print "Sorted numbers: ", num

            sys.stdout.flush()
            self._socket.close()


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4242))
sock.listen(10)

while True:
    canal, address = sock.accept()
    print 'Connection from: ', address
    data = canal.recv(1024)
    print 'Received from the client: ', data, address
    canal.send("Goodbye")
    worker = ThreadWorker(canal)
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    canal.close()
```

In the server Im using a Thread.
Im trying to make the bubble sort run, but I get lots of errors and I dont know if my TCP connection is correct - the errors are on the data receiving side, not the alg.
On the client side, there is nothing more that the connection:

```
message = raw_input("Insert message: ")
sock.connect(('localhost', 4242))
sock.send(message)
data = sock.recv(1024)
print "I received back from the server: ", data
sock.close()
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? 
If Im using split or str on my variable i get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'.
Can anyone help in any way possible?

Comment: "but I get lots of errors" - Please indicate what those errors are. Is there issue in data exchange or in the algorithm?

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
  File line 27, in run
    data_num = self._socket.recv(1024)
  File  line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

-- this is the error I get --
My client receives the Goodbye message, but on the server side I get the above errors.

Comment: If I change the variable numbers method to: number = self._socket.split(" ")

I get the error that:

number = self._socket.split(" ")
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your sequencing:

Client connects, sends data, waits to receive.

Server accepts connection, receives data, sends goodbye.

Client receives Goodbye and closes socket.

Server meanwhile creates Thread, starts it and closes socket. By the time the thread is running both sides have closed socket.

Things to fix:

- don't close the client socket in the server main thread, close it in the Thread created for the client.
- don't recv and send goodbye in the server main thread either.
- after processing data in the thread, actually send the data back and close the client.
- don't close the socket in the client until you recv nothing, indicating the server closed the socket.
- TCP is a byte-oriented protocol. You won't necessarily send a complete message or recv one. You need a protocol and recv until you know the message is complete. Also use `sendall` to ensure the entire message is sent.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try these changes and come back with an answer!